# Angular. Pass selector of one sibling component to another one

Tags: angular

I have 2 sibling components. In `SecondComponent` folder I have the component itself and its child component. So I need to use in `FirstComponent` the child component of the `SecondComponent`. I mean in my `FirstComponent`, specifically in html file I need to use  the html file (selector like 'child-component') of the child component of the `SecondComponent`.

Let's say I have already written code in child component of the `SecondComponent` and I need to reuse it in the `FirstComponent` (They both are siblings, on the same level of indentation, in the components folder).

So in the `first-componen.ts` I need to use `<child-component-of-the-second-component>`.
Sorry that will be too much of the code
but the idea is in the `first-component.ts` file I need to use `<child-component-of-the-second-component>`.

Comment: I'm unable to comprehend your post. Please improve.

Comment: Can you please put some code here what you have been trying for?

Comment: Try to provide us with your file structure and concrete names. This abstract concept is hard to grasp

Comment: Try to provide a sample code along with the description

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right but I think of it like:

your-test.component.html:

```html
<component-a></component-a>
<component-b></component-b>
```

while inside component-b.component.html it looks like this:

```
<component-b-child></component-b-child>
```

right?

You could add the following to your component-b.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('b-child', {read: ComponentBChild}) componentBChild: ComponentBChild;
```

while adding the selector to your component-b.component.html

```
<component-b-child #b-child></component-b-child>
```

Then you can change your your-test.component.html:

```html
<component-a [inputForComponentBChild] = componentB.componentBChild></component-a>
<component-b #componentB></component-b>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be following approach could resolve your issue:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-second-component',
  template: `
    <h1>Second Component</h1>
    <app-first-component [templateRef]="childComponentRef"></app-first-component>
    <template #childComponentRef>
      <app-child-component-of-second-component>
      </app-child-component-of-second-component>
    </template>
  `,
})

export class SecondComponent{}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="display = !display">Toggle content</button>
    <template *ngIf="display" [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef">
    </template>
  `,
})

export class FirstComponent{
  display = false;
  @Input() templateRef: TemplateRef;
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component-of-second-component',
  template: `
    <b>This is child component of second component!</b>
  `,
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {  
  ngOnInit() {
    alert('app-child-component-of-second-component initialized!');
  }  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    alert('app-child-component-of-second-component destroyed!');
  }  
}
```